# how do I Unpack a nested dictionary and return a set with the nested values?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested, set

```
    spring =  {'April': {11,10,9,10,15,15,9,7,7,8,9,8,4,2,-1,-3,4,4,2,8,14,8,4,2,2,4,4,5,10,11,14}, 'May': {15,14,20,22,22,25,15,19,19,22,20,19,10,11,15,9,8,6,20,22,22,20,19,20,19,20,20,20,19,19,17}, 'June': {25,9,8,23,22,25,28,28,18,17,15,33,21,16,20,21,20,20,22,23,19,17,21,22,26,28,20,16,23,25}}

    summer = {'July':{26,27,24,25,25,27,28,26,28,23,20,22,34,25,8,9,17,22,23,25,20,26,23,14,24,27,28,23,25,23,20}, 'August':{8,9,15,25,20,21,24,18,22,25,25,24,26,37,20,20,23,23,27,19,17,22,26,29,24,22,24,28,24,25,23,23}, 'September': {21,26,18,21,27,28,32,23,22,20,29,17,10,11,13,14,17,16,7,9,8,9,13,18,20,20,21,24,23,17}}



    temp_data = {'spring': spring, 'summer': summer}


    for d in temp_data:
        print(d, temp_data[d])
```

When I unpack it yields the result

spring {'April': {2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, -3, -1}, 'May': {6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 19, 20, 22, 25}, 'June': {33, 8, 9, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28}}

summer {'July': {34, 8, 9, 14, 17, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28}, 'August': {37, 8, 9, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29}, 'September': {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 32}}

^^^^^^
this result keeps the numbers in the month, what I need to do is get the numbers from within the months and compare them within the season to see which numbers are the same in every month and then isolate those numbers. So every season should return the numbers that are common in that season.

example output:

```
Temperatures in spring : {18, 19, 22, 23}
Temperatures in summer : {35, 36, 49, 18, 19, 22, 23}
```

so, what my program should do is iterate through the months in the specific season and list the common numbers in set notation... super stuck right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools and set methods for this:

```
import itertools as it
def foo(season):
    combos = list(it.combinations([month for month in season], 2))
    result = set()
    for x in combos:
        temp = (season[x[0]].intersection(season[x[1]]))
        result = result.union(temp)
    return result
```

This function can be applied to each dictionary in turn:

```
def extract(data):
    result = {}
    for x in data:
        temp = {x : foo(data[x])}   #pass each dict to foo function
        result.update(temp) 
        print(f"Temperatures in {x} : {temp[x]}")
    return result
```

[Edit] Call `extract(temp_data)` which calls `foo(data[x])` once for each dict in temp_data, gives this result:

```
Temperatures in spring : {8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 19, 20, 22, 25}
Temperatures in summer : {8, 9, 14, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29}
```

Also the function now returns a new dict of this data.

Comment: The code runs into an attribute error 'dict' object has no attribute 'intersection' in the line 6 where you set temp = ...

Comment: That would happen if you passed ```temp_data``` directly to ```foo```.  I added a calling function to make it more clear; only the individual dicts should be passed to foo. To make it more explicit, ```foo``` could be nested inside ```extract```. It should work now.